# how to maintain data with respect to every user?

Tags: php, jquery, data-synchronization, multi-user

So all the coding ninjas out there , I have recenlty started exploring the world of Web Development ( and its just awesome , i should say ) . I am stuck at problem  .

**What i am doing :** My HTML looks something like this

`<ul data-role="listview" > 
<!-- List items come here --> 
</ul>`

These list items are generated dynamically via an AJAX call to a PHP function ( I am thinking to use Pagination , since the data in the UL may grow ) .

Till now i am using a single User scenario ( only one user accessing the website at a time ) . The data looks ok to me .

**Problem** Now i am thinking to increase the user presence .Many Users login at the same time . I will encounter a situation like :

**User A :**  generated an UL with the current scenario in DB (**say 10 rows** )

**User B enters** and hits a refresh to my UL  and Gone ! User A will no longer have the dataset he/she was working with and now he has **12 rows** ( DB Table got 2 more inserts )

**Question** : Do forgive me if am asking a dumb a question . How do i overcome this multi user scenario accessing same Data but not affecting other Users ?

***It would very helpful if the solution given can be easily digested by a Beginner like me :-)***

**Edit :** 
Let me provide an example :

***User A Logged in :*** 
Currently i have 5 rows in DB like

- Hamlet
- Macbeth
- Brutus
- Caesar
- William

so my UL would look something like this :

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="authors"> 
   <li>Hamlet</li>
   <li>Macbeth</li>
   <li>Brutus</li>
   <li>Caesar</li>
   <li>William</li> 
</ul>
```

Now **User B Logs in** and there has been an extra insertion in the DB

- Hamlet
- Macbeth
- Brutus
- Caesar
- William
- Antonio

so my UL should look ***(only for User B , not for User A )***

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="authors"> 
   <li>Hamlet</li>
   <li>Macbeth</li>
   <li>Brutus</li>
   <li>Caesar</li>
   <li>William</li> 
   <li>Antonio</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: It looks more like a protocol problem than a programmatic problem. You should state what happens when inserting/deleting/modifying rows concurrently by several users and then implement the solution. Furthermore, the protocol will be specific to your domain.

Comment: @clapas : Its only Select operation from the DB . kindly check my Edit . provided an example

Comment: I already understood what you mean. So what is the problem and what you want the solution to be?

Comment: The problem is i am not able to think what the solution will be . Will it be inserting a user entry into the table ? . will it be generating an XML (just a wild guess) for the specific user ?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess: add a column in your table with data that contains the user ID that the data belongs to

Then select that data from your table where the userID matches the current user requesting the data

```
+--------+------+   +--------+---------+--------+
| UserID | Name |   | ItemID | Content | UserID | 
+--------+------+   +--------+---------+--------+
| 1      | John |   | 123    | Lorem.. | 2      | <-- This row belongs to Bill 
| 2      | Bill |   | 124    | Lipsu.. | 1      | <-- This row belongs to John
| 3      | etc. |   +--------+---------+--------+
+--------+------+

-- This query would select data belonging to the user Bill
SELECT `Content` FROM `yourdatatable` WHERE `UserID` = 2
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible , qualifying a row to specific user won't solve the problem since at any moment any User will be seeing the last snapshot of the Table unless he hits a refresh button . According your solution User 1 will only see "124 | Lipsu.." & User 2 will see "123 | Lorem .." ( but ideally User 2 should see both ItemID's i.e. 123,124 . Since he requested the Latest Snapshot , while User 1 is still is ok with the Old Data ) . Do correct wherever i am wrong !

Comment: Also the DB side of the Application is not in my hands (another Team manages it), and asking them for any DB side modifications is not really possible i suppose .